# Cube changes position when I use a script to change its UV mapping

Tags: unity, uv-mapping

I try to code a Minecraft like game with Unity 2017.3. [I found a C# script for creating a UV mapped cube](http://ilkinulas.github.io/development/unity/2016/05/06/uv-mapping.html) with the following layout, using my own texture with 64x64 pixel sides:

[image: MY UV map]

If I run the game my cube is now placed in the air. How do I control its position?

[image: MY cube is not on the ground]

Here is the script I'm using:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof (MeshFilter))]
[RequireComponent(typeof (MeshRenderer))]
public class UVMapping : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {

        float size = 1f;

        Vector3[] vertices = {
            new Vector3(0, size, 0),
            new Vector3(0, 0, 0),
            new Vector3(size, size, 0),
            new Vector3(size, 0, 0),
            new Vector3(0, 0, size),
            new Vector3(size, 0, size),
            new Vector3(0, size, size),
            new Vector3(size, size, size),
            new Vector3(0, size, 0),
            new Vector3(size, size, 0),
            new Vector3(0, size, 0),
            new Vector3(0, size, size),
            new Vector3(size, size, 0),
            new Vector3(size, size, size),
        };

        int[] triangles = {
            0, 2, 1, // front
            1, 2, 3,
            4, 5, 6, // back
            5, 7, 6,
            6, 7, 8, //top
            7, 9 ,8, 
            1, 3, 4, //bottom
            3, 5, 4,
            1, 11,10,// left
            1, 4, 11,
            3, 12, 5,//right
            5, 12, 13 
        };

        Vector2[] uvs = {
            new Vector2(0, 0.66f),
            new Vector2(0.25f, 0.66f),
            new Vector2(0, 0.33f),
            new Vector2(0.25f, 0.33f),
            new Vector2(0.5f, 0.66f),
            new Vector2(0.5f, 0.33f),
            new Vector2(0.75f, 0.66f),
            new Vector2(0.75f, 0.33f),
            new Vector2(1, 0.66f),
            new Vector2(1, 0.33f),
            new Vector2(0.25f, 1),
            new Vector2(0.5f, 1),
            new Vector2(0.25f, 0),
            new Vector2(0.5f, 0),
        };  

        Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter> ().mesh;
        mesh.Clear ();
        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
        mesh.uv = uvs;
        mesh.Optimize (); // this is deprecated
        mesh.RecalculateNormals ();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default Unity cube mesh has its center at the object's pivot ((0, 0, 0) in local space), and extends to `-0.5` and `+0.5` on each axis.

The script you're using creates a new cube-shaped mesh with one corner at the pivot, extending from `0` to `size` on each axis.

So if you're using it to replace a default Unity cube at runtime, you'll find it's shifted by 0.5 units.

You can fix this by adding a quick fixup after your vertices block:

```
for(int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
    vertices[i] -= Vector3.one * 0.5f * size;
```

Or you can go through each line and replace every `size` by `0.5f * size`, 
 and every `0` by `-0.5f * size` (defining an `extents = 0.5f * size` makes this neater)

One last note: each cube you use this script on will create its own copy of the mesh, eating memory and draw calls unnecessarily. You might want to consider grouping these, so that you calculate the mesh only once and share it among many cubes. Or even better, just make the mesh you want offline and import it as an asset that all your cubes can reference.

Comment: Thank you, now it works. There is a white edge on one site, but maybe I can fix the problem myself. 

Comment: Looks like texture filtering. Note that if you give Unity a texture that's non-power-of-two in size (like 3x64 = 192 pixels high), its default behaviour is to stretch/compress it to the nearest power of two for efficiency. That can lead to blended texels where you didn't intend them, so generally it's better to make your textures in power of two sizes when you can.

Comment: And how can I solve the problem with my UV map

Comment: What problem with your UV map would you like to solve?

Comment: I see an white edge on one site

Comment: As described above, making your texture a power of two size will help solve this (so your 0.33f UV y coordinates become 0.25f, and so on). Including padding/bleed around the edges of your textured area will also help. For more details, consider asking this as a new question post.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was very helpful. And thank you for editing the question a little bit.